# how can i make a carousel of this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have this code:

```
initPrevNextButtons: function() {
                $('.link-prev', this.$node).click(this.prev.bind(this)).hide();
                $('.link-next', this.$node).click(this.next.bind(this));
            },
            prev: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.currentPage--;
                $('.link-next', this.$node).show();
                if (this.currentPage <= 0) {
                    this.currentPage = 0;
                    $('.link-prev', this.$node).hide();
                } else {
                    $('.link-prev', this.$node).show();
                };
                var url = this.generateURL(true);
                $.get(url, this.write.bind(this));
            },
            next: function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.currentPage++;
                $('.link-prev', this.$node).show();
                if (this.currentPage >= this.totalItems - 1) {
                    this.currentPage = this.totalItems - 1;
                    $('.link-next', this.$node).hide();
                } else {
                    $('.link-next', this.$node).show();
                };
                var url = this.generateURL(true);
                $.get(url, this.write.bind(this));
            },
```

I have a carousel. And can click to the right and left. But when I am on the left item, the left button will be hidden. And when I am on the end of the right, the right button will be hidden too. But how can I make this code. That I have a carousel?

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your words is that your next/previous icons gets hidden when you move your mouse over them. How many items do you have in the list?

Try commenting the following lines and run the application

```
$('.link-next', this.$node).hide();
$('.link-prev', this.$node).hide();
```

Don't delete just comment them and see if you can see the next/previous icons?